# PROJECT EULER #19 in C

Tags: c

I tried problem 19 on project euler. The answer is 171 but my code gives 1199 which is way off the expected answer. Can somebody please tell me where I'm going wrong?
-- Link to the problem is here : https://projecteuler.net/problem=19

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int count=2;
    int flag1=0;
    int flag2=0;
    int month=1;
    int day=1;
    int year=1901;
    int sunday=0;//count sundays

    while(1)
    {

        //check for leapyears
        if(year%4)
        {
            if((year%100==0 && year%400==0) || year%100!=0)
                flag2=1;
        }

        //update months(31days)
        if((month==1 ||month==3 || month==5 || month==7 || month==8 || month==10|| month==12) && day==31) 
        {
            flag1=1;
            day=1;
            month++;
            if(month==13)
            {
                month=1;
                year++;
                flag2=0;
            }
        }
        //update months(30days)
        if((month==4 || month==6 || month==9 || month==11) &&  day==30)
        {
            flag1=1;
            day=1;
            month++;
        }
        //update month:february
        if(month==2)
        { 
            if((flag2==0 && day==28) || (flag2==1 && day==29))    
            {
                flag1=1;
                day=1;
                month=3;
            }      
        }

        //check sunday of every month
        if(count%7==0 && flag1==1)
        {
            sunday++;
            flag1=0;
        }

        count++;

    day++;        

        if(year==2001)
            break;
    }
    printf("%d\n",sunday);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How have you tried to debug it so far?

Comment: `if(year%4)` is never a leap year so the subsequent century tests are to no avail.

Comment: `leap = year%4==0 && (year%100!=0 || year%400==0);`

Comment: You know questions on SO have to be self-contained?

Comment: I would suggest you to count Sundays for the first year, 1901, both manually and by using your program. If it doesn't work, add prints to your code and try to find where it went wrong.

Answer (score -1):

There are three things wrong.

- *check for leapyears*: `if(year%4)` must be `if (year%4==0)`.
- *update months*: When you go from the last day of a month to the first day of the next month, you forget to increment the day `count`.
- *check sunday of every month*: You do not reset `flag1` until you have encountered a sunday, even if that is not on the first of the month.

The latter two errors can be corrected like:

```
        count += flag1; // account for extra day step
        if (count%7==0 && flag1) sunday++;
        flag1 = 0;      // reset `first of month` flag for this month
```